# QGIS Custom CRS has some glitches?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am georectifying scanned versions of Survey of India maps, which are in
Everest spheroid and india_nepal datum. The exact parameters are:

+proj=longlat +a=6377301.243 +b=6356100.2284 +towgs84=295,736,257,0,0,0,0
+no_defs

I encountered two issues, one minor and one more significant.

1. I define a custom CRS using these parameters. Give it a name
   "Everest_India_Nepal_custom". Save the CRS. Use it when georectifying a
   toposheet. Save the toposheet with this new CRS. (gtif file). But when I
   reopen that gtif file in a new project, its properties show the CRS
   parameters, but do not show the custom name I had given for ease of
   recognition. When saving it said :User 100001: Everest...
   But when opeining it says "User 100009: *Generated CRS....". So it does not
   remember the name I gave. Although the name still shows up in CRS options.
2. bigger problem: if I try to validate this custom CRS by using the
   "calculate" button at the bottom of the custom CRS window, i get rubbish.
   But the CRS definition is correct, and it works--when my rectified topo is
   placed on google earth, it sits perfectly (error <10m).

Comment: Should probably be bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, add a `+wktext` at the end of your proj string. This will preserve your custom CRS including the name.

Otherwise QGIS tries to find a suitable CRS in the EPSG database from the WKT definition in the file, and create a new custom CRS if nothing matches.

For the second one, I can not help you much. I don't use that calculator.

Comment: Great! I have had this problem for some time. Using     +wktext did the trick. Where can I find information about this parameter? I searched in the proj.4 parameters list and didn`t find anyting

Comment: Just one thing, it doesn't work in all cases. I am rasterizing some lines using the GDAL Rasterize tool and the CRS of the result is a generated CRS. The CRS for the lines layer and the project is the same custom CRS.

Comment: @Ernesto561 see http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Which-Proj-4-transforms-are-available-in-GDAL-td5332472.html . For your remaining problem, it might be better to open a new question, adding more details about the CRS you use, and the output you get. You may link here.

Comment: I asked a new question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253475/results-of-layers-created-with-a-custom-crs-are-loaded-with-a-generated-crs